# S3 upload from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload folder in S3, but I have lot of folders which have space between their names. It's an automate process, so could not change the name of the folders manually (from abc d to 'abc d').

```
folder_name = abc d
import os
cmd = 'aws s3 sync'+''+folder_name+'/'+''+s3path+folder_name+'/'
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: Are you receiving a specific error? Try `print(cmd)` to see what it is try to run. You can also use an f-string, such as `cmd = f"aws s3 sync '{folder_name}/' '{s3path}{folder_name}/'"`.

Comment: It's working fine if the folder name is not having any space. It will be fine if I could change the folder name. Name=abc d.... To Name='abc d'

Comment: That code can't possibly work.  Please post the code you're using when asking questions.  As a guess, you need to quote strings in arguments:  `cmd = 'aws s3 sync "'+folder_name+'/" "'+s3path+folder_name+'/"'`

Answer (score 1):

Will be pasting ,my code here. Will be glad if it helps:)

```
!pip install boto3  ##install boto3
!pip install s3fs  ##required package

import boto3
import pandas as pd

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

s3 = boto3.resource(
service_name='s3',
region_name='us-east-2',
aws_access_key_id='',
aws_secret_access_key='')

# Upload files to S3 bucket
s3.Bucket('bucket_name').upload_file(Filename='foo.csv', Key='foo.csv')
s3.Bucket('bucket_name').upload_file(Filename='bar.csv', Key='bar.csv')

for obj in s3.Bucket('bucket_name').objects.all():
    print(obj)
```

Note :

1. the last for loop will print the keys of files that you've
   uploaded (for confirmation).
2. aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key - both of these will be available in
   your aws profile.

Comment: Ohhh great. But suppose I want to change the folder names like if their any space is present then folder name will be inside of single/double quotes